# How can I get the hashkey with .jsk extension?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get a Kakao login release hash key for release on Windows. On the official Kakao website, it says

```
   After app development is complete, when generating a release build 
   APK for distribution, sign with the keystore for release with .jks 
   extension, not the debug keystore. Enter the following command in the 
   terminal to get the release key hash.
```

I need to sign a keystore for release with .jks extension, but there is only .keystore with extension and no keystore for release with jks extension.

this is kakao website

https://developers.kakao.com/docs/latest/ko/getting-started/sdk-android-v1

this is my project folder

[image]

Comment: the document has provided a way to do it. `keytool .....`

Comment: @Horst yes but document says After app development is complete, when generating a release build APK for distribution, sign with the keystore for release with .jks extension, not the debug keystore. Enter the following command in the terminal to get the release key hash.

Comment: that is the file you would create when you want to release your android apk

Comment: @Horst  So you mean when i run that command i get a .jsk file?

Comment: no. I mean you need to create a keystore(jks) for publishing your apk. and that service require  a hash from that keystore (running the command with the file path). FYR: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key